# Why is the Matlab function "feval" needed?

Tags: matlab, function

A function handle can be used to call a function, e.g.

```
f = @sin;
val = f(1.0);
```

so why is `feval` ever needed?

```
val = feval(f, 1.0);
```

When is it useful?

Comment: I find that it makes the code easier to read, since parentheses are used for both indexing and function invocation. Using `feval` makes it clear what we are doing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For `feval`, the first argument can be a quoted string, giving you more flexibility than a function handle. You could do things like having functions with a base name followed by an index as in `fn1`, `fn2`, `fn3`, and then invoke these dynamically using `feval(['fn', num2str(k)], x, y, z);`.

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering if any other language such as Python supports dynamically generated function names?

Comment: Yes, other languages have even more sophisticated mechanisms. You could read up on introspection. Also look for "messages" in Objective-C.

Comment: I would add that, historically, TMW has promoted a shift from `eval` methods to 'controlled' alternatives such as @function handles. In other words, the above construct is easily implemented with @function handles but might still be used in legacy code or by habit.

Comment: I would like to add that even though this *is* possible, it's not the best style to use numbered functions. If you have those, you maybe should reconsider having a function `fn` that takes the index as additional input. The answer to "*why is `feval` ever needed*" should be: "It *was* needed, but nowadays one should evaluate a function handle using parentheses instead."

Answer (score 14):

*Until Release 14 (MATLAB 7), feval was the **way** to evaluate a function handle...* or *to evaluate functions when they are specified by their name.*

Source: [Mental model for `feval()`](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/01/11/mental-model-for-feval/).

Comment: Thanks Oleg, it makes a lot of sense. Also another blog article mentioned in the comments: [More on eval](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/01/04/more-in-eval/)

Comment: As a side note, in 5 years with MATLAB I might have used feval only once.

Comment: This basically means: There **is** no need for `feval` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily always you know what function is supposed to used; there are many examples

here is a silly example: let, in a text file after each number, different word that can be evaluated as a mathematical function, like, mean, min, max, square are represented, and the task is calculating the result after each like,

```
2,square,2,power,4,log,10 ...
```

and you want to write a program to go through this text and calculate the final result ...

another example is for example, I want to define a plot function with user input function handle f, so it must be in a way flexible ...

```
pfun=@(f,x) plot(f(x))
```

Comment: In both cases you can still use function handles.