# How should I rewrite this code to not use feval?

Tags: matlab, refactoring

I recently finished a homework set in my Applied Numerical Methods class and did alright on it.  However, my professor made a note to say I shouldn't use the feval() function because it's outdated.

I'm just wondering what I should use instead.

Here is the code in question

```
%% function file
function E=euler(f,a,b,ya,h)
    t=a:h:b;
    y(1)=ya;
    for i=1:length(t)-1
        y(i+1) = y(i) + h*(feval(f,t(i),y(i)));
    end
     t = t';
     y = y';
     E=t;
     plot(t,y)
     xlabel('t')
     ylabel('y') 
end



%% script file    

h = 0.01;
figure(2)
y1=euler(f, a, b, ya, h);

h = 0.001;
figure(3)
y2=euler(f, a, b, ya, h);

h = 0.0001;
figure(4)
y3=euler(f, a, b, ya, h);
```

How could I write this code to still properly evaluate the Euler function without using the feval function.

Comment: well, what is `f,a,b,ya`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the Matlab function "feval" needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701213/why-is-the-matlab-function-feval-needed)

Answer (score 6):

In a [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/01/11/mental-model-for-feval/) *Loren* states that up until *Release 14* in 2004 you had to use `feval` to evaluate a function handle.

> In Release 14, we removed the need to use `feval` to evaluate function
>   handles. Instead, they can be evaluated directly.

Nowadays you would simply use `f(t(i),y(i))` instead of `feval(f,t(i),y(i))`.