# Evaluate multiple values in a function matlab

Tags: matlab, function, numerical-methods, evaluate

I have defined a function in matlab:

```
function1 = @(x,y,z)[x*y*z,y^2,x+z]
```

Then in the program I want to writ, I want to evaluate the values of this function for (1,2,3).

Outside the program I can use `feval(function1,1,2,3)` and this returns

```
6     4     4.
```

Now inside my program, I want the input to be like this: `output = program(fun, vec)`, where `vec` is a vector like `[1,2,3]`.

If I now call: `feval(fun,vec)` I get the following error message:

```
Error using @(x,y,z)[x*y*z,y^2,x+z]
Not enough input arguments.
```

Can someone tell me how I can evaluate the values of my function when the input is a vector instead of three seperate numbers?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [**comma-separated list**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html). Define your vector `vec` as follows:

```
vec = {1 2 3}
```

or use

```
vec = [1 2 3]
vec = num2cell{vec}
```

and then call `feval`:

```
feval(fun,vec{:})
```

[**It is actually obsolete to evaluate functions with `feval`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701213/why-is-the-matlab-function-feval-needed), the following is equivalent:

```
function1(1,2,3)
function1(vec{:})
```

---

As you want to pass the vector `vec` to your *program* you need to modify your program to either accepted a various number of inputs with `varargin`:

```
program(fun, vec{:))
```

or you change the evaluation of `vec` **inside** your function to `vec{:}`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating [anonymous functions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html), and they can be used with the following syntax:

```
myfun= @(x,y,z)([x*y*z,y^2,x+z])
res=myfun(1,2,3);
vect=[1 2 3]
res2=myfun(vect(1),vect(2),vect(3));
```

In general I would try to avoid using `feval`.

Comment: That works, however let's assume myfun has 10  unknowns, and then the vector has length 10 as well. Then it is a lot of work to write:
res2=myfun(vect(1),vect(2),vect(3), vect(4), vect(5), vect(6), vect(7), vect(8), vect(9), vect(9));

isn't there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You are right, it is tedious. If you follow @thewaywewalk suggestions, you can get it with cell arrays.